# Swiftで独自のカスタムフォントを使いたい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

**前提・実現したいこと**
Swiftでクイズアプリを作っています。
起動画面直後のトップページに、Labelオブジェクトでアプリのタイトルを表示しており、そのフォントをGoogleFontsからダウンロードした「Gotu」というフォントに変えたいです。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
プロジェクトにフォントファイルを追加
→Info.plistファイルにFonts provided by applicationのItem0に「Gotu-Regular.ttf」を追加
→storyboard→Labelオブジェクトを選択→Font→Custom→Family
上記の手順で進めてGotuに変更しようと試みましたが、Familyの中にGotuが見当たりませんでした。

そのため、コードで変更しようと思いViewController.swiftファイル内にコードを記述しました。
しかし、シミュレーターで挙動確認しようとすると起動画面で処理が止まり、Xcodeで

```
Thread 1: "-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

というエラーが発生します。

**該当のソースコード**
Swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var appTitle: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        appTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Gotu-Regular", size: 12)
    }
}
```

**試したこと**
Copy Budle Resources にフォントファイルが無いのかなと思い確認しましたが、有りました。

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
Swift Version 5.3.2
Xcode Version 12.4

Comment: Google FontsからGotuフォントをダウンロードして試してみましたが、「プロジェクトにフォントファイルを追加」した段階でUILabelのCustomフォントでFamilyにGotuが現れるようになりました。「プロジェクトにフォントファイルを追加」したやり方がおかしかったのではないでしょうか。また、あなたのコードを試してみましたが`-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`のエラーは再現することができませんでした。エラー内容から考えて、ご質問中には明記されていない部分の設定か示されていない部分のコードで変なことをしているせいで発生したエラーで、フォントとは関係ない問題のように思われます。どのプロジェクトテンプレートから始めて、どのような操作を行ったのか、より詳細に、再現するためのステップを記述することはできませんか?

Comment: OOPer様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
先程、今一度おかしなところがないか確認していましたら、
Labelオブジェクトに複数の紐付けを行ってしまっておりました。。
そのため、紐付けをひとつに修正しましたところ無事にフォントが変わりました。
なんとも初歩的なミスで質問してしまい申し訳ございませんでした。
ありがとうございました。